# Get th cells in order as them show with a specific flag

Tags: javascript, html

**I want to get the columns(th) with the attribute '*data-grid-column*' in order as them show in the broswer.

Such as a1, a2, B, c1, c2, c3, d1, d2, d3; but i can't code it in mind.

Can anybody give me a solution? many thanks to you!**

```js
$(function(){
  
})
```

```css
.table thead tr th {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    border-color: #ddd #ddd gainsboro;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-width: 1px 1px 7px;
    border-style: solid;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
<table class="table table-primary" id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center" colspan="2">A</th>
            <th class="text-center" rowspan="3" data-grid-column="B">B</th>
            <th class="text-center" colspan="3">C</th>
            <th class="text-center" rowspan="2" colspan="3">D</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center" rowspan="2" data-grid-column="a1">a1</th>
            <th class="text-center" rowspan="2" data-grid-column="a2">a2</th>
            <th class="text-center" data-grid-column="c1">c1</th>
            <th class="text-center" data-grid-column="c2">c2</th>
            <th class="text-center" rowspan="2" data-grid-column="c3">c3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center" colspan="2">c1 + c2</th>
            <th class="text-center" data-grid-column="d1">d1</th>
            <th class="text-center" data-grid-column="d2">d2</th>
            <th class="text-center" data-grid-column="d3">d3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) searches the document for elements matching any valid CSS selector and returns them to you in document order (basically, the order they're shown in). The CSS selector for a `th` element with a `data-grid-column` attribute [is `th[data-grid-column]`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-representation) So:

```
var headers = document.querySelectorAll("th[data-grid-column]");
```

Comment: this get the result B, a1, a2, c1, c2, c3, d1, d2, d3, while i want a1, a2, B, c1, c2, c3, d1, d2, d3

Comment: @Kratos: You said you wanted them in the order shown. That's not the order shown. If you want them in that order, you'll have to go row-by-row, using `querySelectorAll` on the individual rows, and apply your custom logic for how you get that order.